# Trigger io barcode scan doesn't work when it is invoked for the first time

Tags: android, trigger.io

On `Android 2.3.1`, when you use the `trigger.io` code below, the trigger framework doesn't scan the bar-code the first time when it is invoked. Actually the camera opens and the bar-code is scanned, however, after the scanning is complete you see the trigger splash page and the success function doesn't get invoked. It starts working like it should when the scan function is called from the second time on-wards.

```
forge.barcode.scan(function (value) {
   alert("You scanned: "+value);
});
```

Comment: I'm not able to scan it at all. I get a Java error stating "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()" - which is a shame as my app relies on being able to scan barcodes and was only able to test the module by paying for an account.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the app is being forcefully closed when the camera is started, due to device resource constraints.

If you look at the output of "adb logcat" in a terminal, you'll probably see a message about an unhandled intent.

In this case, there's not too much we can do - the Android OS has started killing processes to free up memory. We always keep our wrapper as lightweight as possible, and will continue to look for areas to increase efficiency.

We have only seen this problem occur with any regularity on low-spec devices running later versions of Android. If it's happening a lot for you, check your app's not leaking memory - again, the output of "adb logcat" can show GC activity.